# LWJGL 1.1 Materials are black on macintosh

Tags: macos, opengl, lwjgl, lighting

I have managed to change material colors on linux, but all of my comrades use macbooks.  When I compile and run the program on a mac, the program runs as usual, but materials appear black.  Textures are okay.

The following code uses LWJGL to set lighting.

```
    float[] lightPos={1f,1f,1f,0f};

    //material colors
    float[] matspecular={1,1,1,0};
    float[] matambient={1,1,1,0};
    float[] matdiffuse={0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0};

    //light colors
    float[] lightspecular={1f,1f,1f,1};
    float[] lightdiffuse={0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0};
    float[] lightambient={0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,0};


    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0);

    ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16);
    temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer lightPosition=(FloatBuffer) temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightPos).flip();
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_POSITION, (FloatBuffer)(lightPosition));

    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_SPECULAR, (FloatBuffer) temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightspecular).flip());
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, (FloatBuffer) temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightambient).flip());
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer) temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightdiffuse).flip());

    GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SPECULAR, (FloatBuffer) temp.asFloatBuffer().put(matspecular).flip());
    GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer) temp.asFloatBuffer().put(matdiffuse).flip());
    GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, (FloatBuffer) temp.asFloatBuffer().put(matambient).flip());

    GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SHININESS, 2f);
```

The order I render is:

```
            pollInput();

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        //Creates an orthographic projection from -50,-50 to 50,50.
        //the depth range is 1 to 400
        GL11.glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, 1, 400);

        setLighting();

        //enable face culling, so only the front of a shape is rendered
        GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_FRONT);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);

        GL11.glClearColor(0.5f, 0, 0, 1);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderModel(hills,pitch,yaw,roll);
        GL11.glTranslatef(-20, 20, 0);
        //renderFace(mask,apitch,0,0

        Display.update();
```

note that this is one of three problems I'm having.  Solving any one of them may solve the others. (the others are: rendering textures resets materials, and specular lighting is always from 1,1).  As these are different problems, I will post different questions for them.

Comment: While this is *completely* unrelated, it is nevertheless worth mentioning... Do not issue two separate clear commands like you are currently, that is very inefficient. You can clear both buffers in a single command if you bit-wise `OR` the bits together; there is a reason the buffers are defined as a *bitfield* instead of sequential constant integers.

Comment: More importantly, you have included your projection matrix in the modelling and viewing transform (ModelView matrix). Y.ou can get away with this in some parts of the GL API, but fixed-function lighting is generally NOT one of them. It needs properly distinguishable projection and ModelView matrices, since lighting is ***NOT*** supposed to be done in clip-space. I am at a loss for why this would only create problems on OS X and not Linux, but chances are this is causing at least some of your problems.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose.  While unrelated, it's helpful to know this.  I find OpenGL to be confusing.